# Scala Generics & Reflection Issue

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

I noticed some gap around reflection and generics and I wonder if anybody can help here.

Let say I have the following abstract class:

```
abstract class Animal[T : Eatable: ClassTag] {

     def eat(food: T) : Unit
}
```

And here is one implementation of it:

```
class Dog[DogFood] {

    def eat (food: DogFood) : Unit = ???
}

class DogFood extends Eatable
```

And here I had some method that given an animal, feeds it

```
def feed[T <: Eatable](animal: Animal[T]) : Unit = {
    val isAvailable = Storage.isAvailable[T]
    ???
}
```

Now let say I want to instantiate the implementation class using reflection as it is part of my system configuration:

```
val config = ....
val animalCls = config.getString("animal.type")
val animalInstance = animalCls = Class.forName(animalCls).newInstance

// Issue is here - I can't call this method as it uses classTags!
feed(animalInstance)
```

A solution might be:

```
 val animalCls = config.getString("animal.type").asIsntanceOf[Animal[_]]
```

But then the following call inside feed will fail as it doesn't bind the right type:

```
Storage.isAvailable[T]
```

Any ideas here?

Comment: In the first line you have type restriction `Animal[T : Eatable: ClassTag]` shouldn't it be `Animal[T <: Eatable: ClassTag]` ?

Comment: you are right sorry, problem still there though. This is just a sample code, i missed the "<"

Comment: How is your `Storage.isAvailable` defined and implemented? Does it require `ClassTag` or something?

Comment: Let Say `def isAvailable[T <: Eatable : ClassTag] : Boolean = ??? `

Comment: @but there is no evidence of `ClassTag[T]` in your current example definition of `feed`. Such use would produce a compile error